# TFS2010 - Is there a way to pre-populate a project group

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, active-directory, tfs-process-template

In our shop, all the developers have read only to the code.
Everyone has been put in a group called TFSReader.

In TFS 2005, whenever I create a new project, I have to add the group to the [Project]\Readers group.

We are now looking to upgrade to TFS2010 now and we're wondering
Is there a way to configure TFS to automatically put the TFSReader group under [Project]\Readers?

Should I be messing with the processTemplates?

Comment: I presume you mean that all the developers have read access and that _some_ developers have full access to the code? Otherwise it would be difficult to change it.

Comment: You are correct John. I just want to cut down on instances of me forgetting to add some permissions.  I would have hoped that ms would have implemented something like this in 5 years...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the process template was the right way to go.

I got an answer over at the msdn forums.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/108ad70b-2a4a-4ec4-b8e0-e41d72766484

I downloaded the process template, made a copy and change the GroupsandPermissions.xml file.

I added the Member tag and uploaded the new process.

It worked like a charm!

```
    <group name="Readers" description="Members of this group have access to the team project.">
      <permissions>
        <permission name="GENERIC_READ" class="PROJECT" allow="true" />
        <permission name="VIEW_TEST_RESULTS" class="PROJECT" allow="true" />
        <permission name="GENERIC_READ" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="WORK_ITEM_READ" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
      </permissions>
      <members>
        <member name="MyDomain\TfsReader" />
      </members>
    </group>
```

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a way to pre-populate that I am aware of, what you can do is use the tf perm command, scripted out, and just run that whenever you add a new project.

In your case, you would do (from command line):

```
tf perm /allow:read /collection:http://SERVER:PORT/tfs/COLLECTION /group:TFSREADER $\
```

This says: "Give read permission to the TFS collection for everyone in the group in all files starting at the root of each team project"

If you want to read more about the tf perm command you can here:

[Permission Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dsd05ft.aspx)

Comment: Ngm, would this not be the same thing as giving the group read permissions at the root?  I'm guessing that the group will only have access to the source control & not work items etc.  I'll test it out on monday.

Comment: Yeah, it is version control specific.  The same thing can be done in TFS API.  I am not aware of a way either via TF, TFPT or TFS API that would set it at the WI level for this you would probably need to do work on the template and have a global server permission.  I haven't been down that road before though so I wouldn't be able to provide guidance for that assuming it is possible.